# How to turn off logging for superagent in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, superagent

besides monkeypatching console.log and ignoring lines with `superagent`, is there a way to disable built-in logging in superagent when running in node?

currently, it always logs something like this:

`superagent GET https://example.com/test?query=blah -> 200 +5ms`

I can't find this in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As many Node packages, `superagent` uses `debug` to show debugging information. The problem likely occurs because debugging was enabled for all namespaces (`*`).

As [the documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#wildcards) explains, if all namespaces are included with a wildcard, some can be excluded:

```
process.env.DEBUG = '*,-superagent';
```